# Simple wireless transmitter for notification when circuit turned on

Tags: communication, wireless, bluetooth, 12v

I have a simple home project I'd like to implement. Being a electronics newbie I'm not sure exactly how to go about it.

Basically, I'd like to build a device that is attached to a (12V) power supply line that simply sends a wireless signal/alert to my smart phone when the power is turned on i.e. current running through the wire.

The signal only needs to be transmitted roughly 1-3m, so I assume some sort of Bluetooth transmitter spliced into, and piggybacking off the power running through the 12V wire will suffice?  The device does not need to receive signals i.e. one-way communication only.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realize now my initial post was lacking a little detail - newbie to electronics and forums. Anyway, the application will likely be outside, with no wifi, and at times no data/internet of any kind. Furthermore, I would prefer a relatively "hands free" notification solution e.g. phone simple vibrates, emits a sound etc. As such a solution via email would be unsuitable (but thanks for the advise anyway). I assume therefore that the BLE chip/board is perhaps the right way to go. I'll take a look. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Raspberry Pi with a wifi board. Feed the voltage (after regulating to 3.3 V) to a GPIO pin. Monitor the pin, and send yourself an email when it triggers.

Alternatively, power it directly from the 12 V so that it is off until it's needed. Have the message sent automatically after boot. Then you can program it to shutdown.

[image: raspberry pi]

Comment: ESP8266 would be far cheaper, and doesn't need to be on all the time.

Comment: @cranphin probably right. I posted this before the other answer. Still this would have way more capabilities, should the need arise. A PI is maybe $10-$30 bucks. Not too bad.

Comment: @cranphin Updated the answer. This doesn't need to be on all the time either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have WiFi then use an [ESP8266](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfoK23qYjVAhVILsAKHdbBB0EQFgiIATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FESP8266&usg=AFQjCNH_-awNo8u4ErttL4-bXQl54We7gQ): -

[image]

You'll need a power supply and you'll need to be able to put some firmware into it.

> Anyway, the application will likely be outside, with no wifi, and at
>   times no data/internet of any kind.

Then there is the ESP32S combined blue-tooth and WiFi module: -

[image]

There are quite a few options for blue-tooth/WiFi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try NRF51 based boards. which is cheaper and uses BLE to communicate.[image]